# How do I run software without rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to this respec TDD: Once I've tested all my specifications and the software is complete, is there any way to extract the software out of all the tests and run it without using the `rspec` command?

Comment: You want to reuse the RSpec tests somehow? Why?

Comment: i am making this small pdf builder application which i want to use to generate graphical pdf's using prawn gem ... It generate a resume in pdf given all assets and data. so i was using rspec to generate my resume in pdf, then i thought this could be used for any other type of application where the assets("images") and data are different say for example a report generation ... or am i just lame to think like that.

Comment: do you have specs and code in the same directory? Why is it a problem? Normally you would put your specs in a `spec` folder and your 'real' code in `lib`.

Comment: (your idea is good by the way - trying to do somehting generic out of something that is working for a specific case. That is how libraries are born.)

Comment: i have some classes in the same spec file ... should i just extract it out ?

Comment: yes - your "real" classes should not be in the spec file. It is a good way to get started but once you think they are nice and fine they should go into their own files. Production and test code separated.

Comment: A very common project layout is to have your application code in a subdirectory called lib, and your specs in a subdirectory called spec.

Comment: As an aside, I think you may want to have a closer look at your specs. If you can fully run your program via rspec, your tests are too coarse. You should look into mocking and stubs so as to test individual methods, rather than have one test dependent on various bits of unrelated code.